# Using ojalgo: Create Matrix from Array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, ojalgo

I am trying to use [ojAlgo](http://www.ojalgo.org/) to solve some linear algebra problems in Java. I am asking if there is any "clever" way to create a matrix using an existent array.

This is my naive approach:

```
final double[][] myArray = {
    { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 },
    { 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 },
    { 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 }
};

final Builder<PrimitiveMatrix> myBuilder = PrimitiveMatrix.getBuilder(myArray.length, myArray[0].length);
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[0].length; j++) {
        myBuilder.set(i, j, myArray[i][j]);
    }
}

final PrimitiveMatrix myMatrix = myBuilder.build();
System.out.println(myMatrix);
```

This works, but it is too much trouble to do every single time. I could write a class that does just that and call it every time I want to do it, but I wonder if there is a simpler approach.

Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Isn't `double[][] myArray` a matrix?

Comment: Is it? Can I multiply it with other matrices somehow?

Comment: matrix multiplication have some rule.

Comment: Matrix multiplication and many other matrix operations is what linear algebra is all about. Since these operations are too many to handle correctly and efficiently on my own, I downloaded the library ojalgo (there are more, but this is the one I liked the most). This probably works fine, but I have a problem creating what ojalgo thinks of as a Matrix: PrimitiveMatrix.
Hence my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want to create an (immutable) BasicMatrix instance? and did you read the [ojAlgo Getting Started](https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/wiki/Getting-Started) wiki page regarding choosing between different matrix implementations and how to instantiate them?

There is a class/method 
org.ojalgo.array.ArrayUtils#wrapAccess2D(double[][]) 
that may help you, but that depends on what your next step is...

...or why don't you simply call `PrimitiveMatrix.FACTORY.rows(myArray);`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the trouble to answer my question. And I would like to personally express my gratitude to you for writing ojalgo! Your answer was very helpful! I had actually read the wiki page you mentioned, but I did not understand it very well since I am relatively new to all this (plus copy-paste from the site failed me miserably due to importing problems).